How to find element in selenium ignoring apostrophes
Can anyone tell me how to use selenium to search for something ignoring apostrophes? For example, if i search for the word "Hes", and inside the page content contains "He's" it will find it?
Thanks

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

In general you can get the source code with Selenium (but this also works with BS4). Beautifulsoup has an html parser. You use it to search in the source itself. You can use fuzzywuzzy to create a list of words that you are considering.
Another option would be to parse for words with Selenium and xpath. (you can also use regex in the xpath). However, xpath becomes confusing very quickly.
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78338347/how-to-find-element-in-selenium-ignoring-apostrophes")

page_source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')

query = "Hes"
strings_to_search = ["he's", "she's", "it's", "his"]

best_match = None
best_ratio = 0
for string in strings_to_search:
    ratio = fuzz.ratio(query, string)
    if ratio > best_ratio:
        best_ratio = ratio
        best_match = string

print("Best match:", best_match)

search_results = soup.find_all(text=re.compile(re.escape(best_match), re.IGNORECASE))

for result in search_results:
    print(result)

driver.quit()


There is no "above" or "below"; the answers on Stack Overflow are sorted dynamically, based on each visitor's individual preferences.
